# AppCompat.DayNight определить включена ли ночная тема в режиме AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO

Tags: android

Собственно сам вопрос как определять включена ли ночная тема, а именно темная, когда установлен режим `AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO` при использовании темы `AppCompat.DayNight`.

Нужно для того что бы показывать стиль темной карты точнее не показывать его днем в режиме авто.
если получаю вот так

```
 public boolean isDArkTheme() {
    boolean isDark;
    isDark = themeName.equals(MyAppInfo.DARK_THEME)||themeName.equals(MyAppInfo.AUTO_THEME);
    return isDark;
}
```

то в авто режиме включается ночная карта, но днем она мне не нужна))) ВОт собственно и назрел вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Собственно все решилось довольно просто:

```
boolean nightTheme = false;
    int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
    if (currentNightMode == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES){
        nightTheme = true;
    }
```